# How do I get functionality in Grid.MVC to work properly with Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview, grid.mvc

I am using Grid.MVC with my ASP.NET MVC 4 Project.  I am also using Bootstrap.  I am not sure if there is a conflict between the stylesheets, or the Javascript between the two, or if it is something else altogether.  I have the datagrid in a partialview.  I don't know if maybe that is causing the issue, but:
1) when I add ".Sortable(true)" to the end of each column, the column headings change to red, but when I click them it reloads the page and my grid is gone.
2)  When I rollover the rows on the grid, they don't highlight.  When I click on the rows they don't highlight either.  I know that the row is selected however because I created a test "alert" that pops up when the row is selected.
Jquery and Bootstrap are declared on the _Layout.cshtml shared view.
How do I get this grid.MVC functionality to work properly?
Below is the partialview for the grid:

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/mvcGrid")
 @Styles.Render("~Content/mvcGrid")
 @using GridMvc.Html
 @model List<IntegrationQueryToolWebApp.Models.Request>

 @Html.Grid(Model0.Named("requestGrid").Columns(columns =>
 {
      columns.Add(data => data.id).Titled("ID").Sortable(true);
      .....
 })
 <script>
      $(function ()  {
           pageGrids.requestsGrid.onRowSelect(fuinction (e)  {
                alert(e.row.id);
           });
      });
 <script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/mvcGrid")
@Styles.Render("~Content/mvcGrid")
```

should be:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/mvcGrid.js")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/mvcGrid.css")
```

And you have a typo error between

```
@Html.Grid(Model0.Named("requestGrid").Columns
```

and

```
pageGrids.requestsGrid.onRowSelect
```

request**s** / request